# Tag para arquivos de texto de exportação e importação?

Tags: debate, tags

Recentemente foi feita [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92537/o-que-%C3%A9-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sqlserver) a respeito de posições num arquivo de exportação e importação. Na verdade o autor da pergunta queria saber como fazer para ler um layout deste arquivo, mas não consegui pensar numa tag apropriada para isso.

Sugestões?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDI (Electronic Data Interchange).
Intercâmbio Eletrônico de Dados, tradução de EDI, é um padrão comercial para troca estruturada de arquivos. Esses arquivos possuem documentação de seu conteúdo, que podem incluir desde multiplos HEADERs (cabeçalhos) ou mesmo TRAILERs (equivalente a rodapé).
Cada linha de informação é chamada de Registro Detalhe e todos as linhas com essa informação possuem o mesmo número de caracteres.
Um bom exemplo deste tipo de arquivo é o CNAB da [FEBRABAN](http://www.febraban.org.br/) que possuem modelos de 240, 400 e 1000 posições, normatizando a troca de arquivos entre empresas e bancos ou entre os bancos.

Procurei esta tag no STACK e ela ainda não existe.

Comment: Realmente tem até [artigo na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDI). Vamos ver se a comunidade gosta do termo.

Comment: E se fizer exatamente isto mas não estiver usando EDI? EDI é apenas uma das soluções que usam esta ferramenta.